# How i can add mail.jar to oracle sql developer to solve this error

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have looked at many postings on the ( I need to add the `mail.jar` and `activation.jar` to oracle Sql developer ):

```
 "javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException:No provider for Address type: rfc822"...
```

I have written other classes in java that are used by Oracle `Forms6i`, but can't get this email portion to work. The code that seems to be failing is:

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class EnvoyerEmail {

    private String username = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
    private String password = "****";

    public void envoyer() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("yyyyyy@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Test email");
            message.setText("Bonjour, ce message est un test ...");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Message_envoye");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnvoyerEmail test = new EnvoyerEmail();
        test.envoyer();
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the error mentioned above when it tries to send it. I assure you that I have the mail.jar, activation.jar, pop3.jar, mailapi.jar, smtp.jar, imap.jar in the class path. So that is not the problem.
I was suggested on an Oracle Forum that this will need to be signed. I'm very ignorant of this (the java experience that I have is with JSP), but thought that I got things `"secured/signed"`, but I still keep getting the same problem.

Comment: what are you doing exactly, that you would need to add a JAR to Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: i need to execute the java code inside sql developer . i load the java code compiled inside folder java (sql developer) and i'll create a procedure and execute it with EXEC.Nameofprocudr;

Comment: you mean, you need to create Stored Java Procedures, so you can execute the Java inside the JVM running for the Oracle Database?

Comment: You have too many jar files in the class path.  If you're using JDK 8 or earlier, you only need mail.jar.  If you're using a newer JDK, you also need activation.jar.

Comment: Thank you all but i don't know how i can add a mail.jar or activation.jar to sql developer to execute my java class